# How to overlay a transparent video on Webcam?

Tags: wpf, overlay, webcam, transparent

I am using WPF to open a webcam. Now what i need to do is overlay the webcam with the transparent video. I do not want any background to be seen while overlaying the video on the webcam. I am coding in WPF. Is there any way how could i achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried using the `Opacity` property?

Comment: Yes, i have added the opacity property to it. But nothing seems to be working. Could you provide me with examples or links as to how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the video first on After Effects or similar and set the container to this video over the one that you use to open the webcam. There is a lot of options of how to make transparent background. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJ44S1hC0UA) is a link with a video that explains how to get this on After Effects.

Hope it helps.